# Send GET request with bearer token and json body in SWift

Tags: json, swift, request, get, bearer-token

I'm new to swift and I tried to make a get request to a api, but couldn't come up with an working result yet. All examples I tried but not worked at all

I need to send a json body to https://pincood.com/pincood/public/api/user/details and in Authorization I passed Bearer token like this "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcGluY29vZC5jb20vcGluY29vZC9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3VzZXIvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2Njc4MjMxNzAsImV4cCI6MTY2ODE4MzE3MCwibmJmIjoxNjY3ODIzMTcwLCJqdGkiOiJVemo4bFp3ek16Z2FIV25QIn0.oCAk6db9c2BAhEGgU2gziYm2RX3hLbAtPUc7KQzIYWs" with GET request.

And in the output the data will display like this:

The json body only contains of one value

{
"id": 2,
"referral_code": "pn7R7m",
"referance_referral_code": "",
"first_name": "Uzma",
"last_name": "ansari",
"payment_mode": "CASH",
"email": "",
"gender": "MALE",
"birth_date": "2022-06-23",
"mobile": "9326257573",
"country_code": "+91",
"picture": "https://pincood.com/pincood/public/storage/user/profile/9326257573.png",
"device_token": "dW_jfRo94fM:APA91bFluxLzYICoYw6MslhYWEzxET8NYKH27MzSmQNRT6fNLdo6eAIB6KBZv9IvkFrSHUA2GUD1RfNw1e2XVdIdSZjDf-627PRLopzOwInifGdWIA4k-nIwLDghycCAlhwW0KJy76Xe",
"device_id": "ceae4b934e63a578",
"device_type": "android",
"login_by": "manual",
"social_unique_id": null,
"latitude": null,
"longitude": null,
"stripe_cust_id": null,
"wallet_balance": 0,
"rating": "5.00",
"otp": 811078,
"updated_at": "2022-11-06 12:44:01",
"emergency_contact1": "9999999999",
"emergency_contact2": "",
"deleted_at": null,
"currency": "₹",
"sos": "911",
"rental_content": "Dummy Content",
"outstation_content": "Dummy Content"
}

And I tried in the implementation like this
My Model :

struct TokenResponse: Codable {
let id : Int
let referral_code: String
let referance_referral_code: String
let first_name: String
let last_name: String
let payment_mode: String
let email: String
let gender: String
let birth_date: String
let mobile: String
let country_code: String
let picture: String
let device_token: String
let device_id: String
let device_type: String
let login_by: String
let social_unique_id: String
let latitude: String
let longitude: String
let stripe_cust_id: String
let wallet_balance: Int
let rating: String
let otp: Int
let updated_at: String
let emergency_contact1: String
let emergency_contact2: String
let deleted_at: String
let currency: String
let sos: String
let rental_content: String
let outstation_content: String

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case referral_code
    case referance_referral_code
    case first_name
    case last_name
    case payment_mode
    case email, gender
    case birth_date
    case mobile
    case country_code
    case picture
    case device_token
    case device_id
    case device_type
    case login_by
    case social_unique_id
    case latitude, longitude
    case stripe_cust_id
    case wallet_balance
    case rating, otp
    case updated_at
    case emergency_contact1
    case emergency_contact2
    case deleted_at
    case currency, sos
    case rental_content
    case outstation_content
}
```

}

My function from where I trid to call my api

```
func getRequest(){
   let url = URL(string: "https://pincood.com/pincood/public/api/user/details/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcGluY29vZC5jb20vcGluY29vZC9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3VzZXIvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2Njc4MjMxNzAsImV4cCI6MTY2ODE4MzE3MCwibmJmIjoxNjY3ODIzMTcwLCJqdGkiOiJVemo4bFp3ek16Z2FIV25QIn0.oCAk6db9c2BAhEGgU2gziYm2RX3hLbAtPUc7KQzIYWs")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Session": "fb4e7f9b-0f31-4709-",
  "AUthorization":"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcGluY29vZC5jb20vcGluY29vZC9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3VzZXIvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2Njc4MjMxNzAsImV4cCI6MTY2ODE4MzE3MCwibmJmIjoxNjY3ODIzMTcwLCJqdGkiOiJVemo4bFp3ek16Z2FIV25QIn0.oCAk6db9c2BAhEGgU2gziYm2RX3hLbAtPUc7KQzIYWs"
]

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
  guard error == nil else { return }
  guard let data = data, let _ = response else { return }
  // handle data
  do{
                    //here dataResponse received from a network request
                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                 let codabledata = try decoder.decode(TokenResponse.self, from: data)
                    print(codabledata)
                 //Response result
                //  Completion(codabledata)
                    
                } catch let parsingError {
                    print("Error", parsingError)
                }
}.resume()
}

getRequest()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example code with the "modified" url string, and the corresponding data model that needs to match the `json` data you get from the server:

EDIT-1: with a `callback` from the asynchronous function.

Use it like this:

```
getRequest() { results in
    print(results)
}

func getRequest(callback: @escaping (TokenResponse?) -> Void) {
    let theToken =  "...."
    
    if let url = URL(string: "https://pincood.com/pincood/public/api/user/details") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Session": "fb4e7f9b-0f31-4709-",
            "Authorization":"Bearer \(theToken)"
        ]
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase  // <-- here
                let codabledata = try decoder.decode(TokenResponse.self, from: data)
                callback(codabledata)  // <-- here
            } catch {
                print(error)
                callback(nil)  // <-- here
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

and

```
struct TokenResponse: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let referralCode, referanceReferralCode, firstName, lastName: String
    let paymentMode, email, gender, birthDate: String
    let mobile, countryCode, picture, deviceToken: String
    let deviceId, deviceType, loginBy: String // <--
    let socialUniqueId, latitude, longitude, stripeCustId: String?  // <--
    let walletBalance: Int
    let rating: String
    let otp: Int
    let updatedAt, emergencyContact1, emergencyContact2: String
    let deletedAt: String?
    let currency, sos, rentalContent, outstationContent: String
}
```

You will need to consult the API docs to determine which properties are optional. In that case add `?` to them.

EDIT-2: passing the token to the function:

```
func getRequest(token: String, callback: @escaping (TokenResponse?) -> Void) {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://pincood.com/pincood/public/api/user/details") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Session": "fb4e7f9b-0f31-4709-",
            "Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"  // <-- here
        ]
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let codabledata = try decoder.decode(TokenResponse.self, from: data)
                callback(codabledata)  // <-- here
            } catch {
                print(error)
                callback(nil)  // <-- here
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
getRequest(token: "your-token-here") { results in
    print(results)
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion but I already checked this things.

Comment: And If I want to pass parameter in that then what will the format?

Comment: P.S, you should remove your 'secret" token from your question/code. Pass parameter, in or out, or both?

Comment: updated my answer with a callback from the asynchronous `getRequest(...)`

Comment: Side note, since the codingkeys match the variables names in snakecase vs camelcase, you could have used a codingKeyStrategy on the `JSONDecoder` avoiding all the declaration of the `enum CodingKeys`

Comment: good point, I'll update my answer with that. Note: `deviceId` and `stripeCustId` and `socialUniqueId`

Comment: Your first answer also working good, now I want pass parameter with bearer token so I canot remove secret key

Comment: updated my answer (EDIT-2) with passing the token to the function. Remove your token from your post by editing your post, and replace it with "my-token" or something like that.

Comment: I think, I ask you question that is wrong. I want parameter pass means I want to pass parameter in the api call httpBody

Comment: what parameter do you want to pass, and how do you want to use it. Note, this is **very** basic Swift. If you don't understand how to do this, you need to read the **fundamental basics of Swift** before coding your App. See:  https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html